# Information about the output of %qiskit_backend_overview

Tags: qiskit, error-correction

Does anyone know where can I find more information about the meaning of some parameters outputted by `%qiskit_backend_overview` ?  I mostly refer to "Avg. T1/T2", "Avg. CX Err." and "Avg. Meas. Err.". Please see the screenshot. I know they are average errors, but how would them influence my decision to pick one or another backend.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

T1 is decoherence time. It is the time taken by the state |1> to decohere to the state |0> due to noise. So we would like T1 to be as large as possible to perform our tasks on that qubit without getting affected by error.
Similarly T2 is dephasing time. It describes how long the phase of a qubit stays intact. It is the time taken by a qubit to go from $|+⟩=1/√2(|0⟩+|1⟩)$ to $|−⟩=1/√2(|0⟩−|1⟩)$ and vice-versa. So We would also like T2 to be as large as possible. 
So you have to choose the backend where both T1 and T2 are higher. That backend device is less prone to error.

Comment: This answer is not correct:
1. T1 is the time it takes to reach 1/e of the way from |1> to |0>, statistically (the qubit is not in superposition between 0 and 1, its state is either |0> or |1>, but for some shots due to the noise it will flip to |0>).
2. For T2 it's not from |+> to |-> but from |+> to the center of the Bloch sphere.

Comment: Can you please provide any source where this  T1 and T2 variables are explained?

Comment: They're explained in the textbook of Nielsen and Chuang and I guess that in other textbooks as well. And survey papers about quantum computing, like arxiv:1904.06560.